# Single.php loses it's formatting

Tags: posts

I needed to use the category name as a class for the H1, and also needed to exclude category 2. So I botched together the PHP code below. It works fine except the post looses it's formatting. I know that `get_post_format()` is what applies the format, but when I add it, it doesn't seem to do anything. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Ok here is the entire Single.php, sorry if i'm not clear on what I was asking I'm a bit of a Wordpress newbie. What I'm trying to achieve is to have the title of the single post to have 2 classes:
1: .category-heading 
2: .heading-"the slug of the category" eg .heading-featured

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying all single posts.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage WDM
 * @since WDM 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>


    <div id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" class="clear" role="main">



            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            $excludedcats = array(2);
            $count = 0;
            $categories = get_the_category();
            foreach($categories as $category) {
                $count++;
                if ( !in_array($category->cat_ID, $excludedcats) ) {
                    echo '<h1 class="category-heading ' . sprintf( __( "heading-%s" ), $category->slug ) . '" >';

                    if( $count != count($categories) ){
                        echo " ";
                    }

                }
                } 
                single_post_title();
                echo '</h1>';
                the_content(); 
                ?>


                <div class="related-posts-div">

                <?php wp_related_posts()?> 
                </div>

                <nav class="nav-single">
                    <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'wdm' ); ?></h3>
                    <span class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&larr;', 'Previous post link', 'wdm' ) . '</span> %title' ); ?></span>
                    <span class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&rarr;', 'Next post link', 'wdm' ) . '</span>' ); ?></span>
                </nav><!-- .nav-single -->



                <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: what was the code of single.php before your edits? did it have a div with `post_class()`?

Comment: I suspect you have broken markup.  Why is the opening `<h1>` tag inside a foreach and then inside and if, while the only closing h1 is not?

Comment: I'm a little confused here. `Single.php` is for looping through single posts, but you seem to be outputting a title for each category of each post (providing it is not category 2). You are also closing `<\h1>` outside of the `if` statement, so you are adding that to your markup whether or not it is needed. Also, you are checking that a category ID is in the `$excludedcats` array, but you can exclude them when making the `$categories` object if you wish. Could you perhaps edit your question to explain your needs better? Also, it appears you haven't added all of `single.php` - please add it all.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Just to clarify - you want posts that are in category 2 included, but just not listed under `class=""`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, try this (untested, so excuse any minor typos/syntax errors).

I have amended so that The Loop first checks that there is Posts to show. I've also removed the need for `$count` and the addition of `' '` by adding any matches to an array, and then outputting them using `join()`.

Hopefully I've not gone down the incorrect route and it will be suitable for your needs.

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying all single posts.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage WDM
 * @since WDM 1.0
 */

get_header();
?>

    <div id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" class="clear" role="main">
<?php
            if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();

                    $excludedcats = array(3);
                    $categories = get_the_category();

                    $title_cats = array(); // Initialise the arry to avoid errors when checking it

                    foreach($categories as $category) :

                        /** Check to see if the category needs to be added to the class="" of the title */
                        if(!in_array($category->cat_ID, $excludedcats)) :
                            $title_cats[] = 'heading-'.$category->slug;
                        endif;

                    endforeach;

                    /** Output the title. We are checking that there were actually category headings here as well, so that class="" is properly formatted */
                    echo '<h1 class="category-heading'.
                        sprintf(__('%1$s'),
                            /** %1$s */ (!empty($title_cats)) ? ' '.join(' ', $title_cats) : ''
                        ). // end sprintf()
                    '">'; // end <h1>
                    single_post_title();
                    echo '</h1>';

                    /** Output the content */
                    the_content(); 
?>
                    <div class="related-posts-div">
                        <?php //wp_related_posts()?>
                    </div>

                    <nav class="nav-single">
                        <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'wdm' ); ?></h3>
                        <span class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&larr;', 'Previous post link', 'wdm' ) . '</span> %title' ); ?></span>
                        <span class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&rarr;', 'Next post link', 'wdm' ) . '</span>' ); ?></span>
                    </nav><!-- .nav-single -->

                    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I just get a blank screen :(

Comment: No errors? Ok, I have a new blog I'm just setting up, will do some debugging and update...

Comment: Ok, so I've tested and found a missing '"' was the issue. I've also commented out `wp_related_posts();`, as it's not a native WP function. Presumably you have a plugin for displaying related posts?

Comment: Have also just corrected another small error, hopefully this is what you were after?

Comment: Thank you, the padding & line-height has been removed in the body of the text on the post, but i"m sure i can add this via CSS

Comment: Yes exactly. Everyone's tastes are different, although if you had it before, you may just need to slightly alter your CSS to take in to account changes.